# How to use SVG filters and <base> tag together

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, filter, blur

Below code works on home page where "page URL" == "base URL"

but fails on any other page

```
<svg>
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
  </filter>

  <image id="svg-image" xmlns:href="http://x.com/image.jpg"       
         filter="url(#blur)">
  </image>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to reference "only the filter" from an external svg file ?

eg:

1.External file @(http://localhost/somewhere/external.svg)

```
<svg>
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

2.HTML document @(http://localhost/elsewhere)

```
<svg>
  <image id="svg-image" xmlns:href="http://x.com/image.jpg"       
         filter="url(/somewhere/external.svg#blur)">
  </image>
</svg>
```

Comment: In reference to the title, probably best not to do that.

Comment: @RobertLongson my dilemma is that SVG is used at only one place(but necessary) and BASE is used site-wide. So I just wanted to have a work-around if possible ?

Comment: Stop using base or stop using filters (or clip-paths or markers or masks) or stop using Chrome (or IE or Safari or Opera).

Comment: @RobertLongson  very nice of you, thanks !

Comment: Your other alternative is to move all SVG into a single standalone file and then embed it via `<object>` or `<iframe>` tags so that the `<base>` tag is in a different document and will then not affect the SVG.

Comment: @RobertLongson  I'll try, but it'll become a little more complex because Image needs to be changed for every user. That's why I wanted only the filter in external file. So eventually, I will have to get rid of <base>

Answer (score 0):

Using a filename in your `url()` like that should work.  Especially if you are referencing the current file.  That will fix your problem with `<base>`.

However not all browsers support pointing to another file (yet).

Incidentally, your `xmlns:xlink` attribute is wrong. That should be `xlink:hef=""`.

Comment: actually it was xmlns:href="" originally , i mixed it up with w3 reference link while removing to make it look smaller.

Comment: no it's not working.  i have mod_rewrite on (problem?) but it doen't even work with absolute reference. Is there a problem in svg filter definition ?

Comment: @user3380710 No, as stated in the answer, not all browsers support it. Firefox does for instance, but Chrome only supports **some** filters and I don't know which ones, perhaps gaussian blur is not one of them. Your best bet is to stop using the `<base>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just Don't  ||  !possible

(as suggested by @RobertLongson and @PaulLeBeau)